# Is there an Azure cosmos db / Azure SQL database function to subscribe to data changes like in Firestore?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-firestore, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

**For example to get real-time updates in firestore**

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

***How can I do that with Azure cosmos db or Azure SQL database, whichever one is possible***?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're looking for is Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed.

From the above link:

> Change feed in Azure Cosmos DB is a persistent record of changes to a
> container in the order they occur. Change feed support in Azure Cosmos
> DB works by listening to an Azure Cosmos container for any changes. It
> then outputs the sorted list of documents that were changed in the
> order in which they were modified. The persisted changes can be
> processed asynchronously and incrementally, and the output can be
> distributed across one or more consumers for parallel processing.